# Errno 13 Permission denied Django Upload File

Tags: django, django-admin

I've looked at all the other solutions but nothing seems to work for me. I have this in my settings.

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/Desktop/myapp/media/'
MEDIA_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/'
```

This in my admin.py

```
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='images/')
```

I am running this on the localhost server at the moment. When I try to upload an image in admin and save it, I get the error:

`[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Desktop'`

I've tried changing the mode using `chmod` and `chown`, but I still get the same error. I have even checked lsof -i and Python does seem to have access to this folder. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well I seem to have answered my own question. It was a very minor issue as it turns out. All I did was change the media root to the complete path and voila.

```
MEDIA_ROOT = 'Users/username/Desktop/myapp/media/'
```

Answer (score 10):

I just had the same problem with the absolute path, but I realised something else. I was joining the path like this:

```
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "/media")
```

But, as stated by the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join):

> If a component is an absolute path, all previous components are thrown
>   away and joining continues from the absolute path component.

So removing the root slash solves the problem:

```
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
```

Cheers.